# Kubernetes dashboard pods is not running

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-dashboard

I'd set up kubernetes with kubeadm, and launched dashboard by:

> kubectl apply -f
>   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml

and checked pod status:

> kubectl gets pods --all-namespaces

But it is not running. It's in "containerCreating" status.

> kube-system   kubernetes-dashboard-5bd6f767c7-v5g8q  0/1
>   ContainerCreating    0    29m

I checked log by:

> kubectl logs kubernetes-dashboard-5bd6f767c7-v5g8q 
>   --namespace=kube-system

And it says:

> Error from server (BadRequest): container "kubernetes-dashboard" in
>   pod "kubernetes-dashboard-5bd6f767c7-v5g8q" is waiting to start:
>   ContainerCreating

I did all the steps to install the dashboard. But not sure what's wrong here.
Would you like to help me?

Comment: try running `kubectl --all-namespaces=true describe po kubernetes-dashboard-5bd6f767c7-v5g8q` to get some more details on the error occouring

Comment: You can also try installing kubernetes dashboard using helm and see if that works. Helm is a package manager for Kubernetes, you can find many useful packages there. https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/kubernetes-dashboard

Comment: If you behind a proxy you can check 'docker pull ...' command for kube-dashboard image. Possible proxy isn't configured for docker